# springboot create bean 2 times

Tags: java, spring, javafx

I have JavaFX application with springboot. The problem is one bean is created 2 times with @PostConstruct and got an exception about serial port already been used. 
Hovewer, i noticed that I have both @SpringBootApplication which alreade include @ComponentScan and @Configuration annotations. And i have SpringConfig class in root package.

**Main.class**

```
package sample;

@SpringBootApplication
public class AppStart extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/primal.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("ИС СиАТВ АО ГНЦ НИИАР");
        primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("/icon.png"));
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1400, 900));
        createTray();
        primaryStage.show();

        primaryStage.setOnCloseRequest(event -> {
            primaryStage.hide();
        });

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);

        SpringApplicationBuilder builder = new SpringApplicationBuilder(AppStart.class);
        builder.headless(false);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = builder.run(args);

        launch(args);
    }
```

**SpringConfig**

```
package sample;
@Configuration
    @PropertySource({"classpath:com.properties", "classpath:application.properties"})
    @ComponentScan
    public class SpringConfig {

        @Bean
        public SerialPort serialPort(@Value("${serialPort.portName}") String portName){
            return new SerialPort(portName);
        }

        @Bean
        public AnnotationMBeanExporter annotationMBeanExporter(){
            AnnotationMBeanExporter annotationMBeanExporter = new AnnotationMBeanExporter();
            annotationMBeanExporter.addExcludedBean("dataSource");
            return annotationMBeanExporter;
        }
    }
```

**ComReader - this class created 2 times and invoke exception by openPort() function**

```
package sample.Model
@Component
public class ComReader {

    @Autowired
    private EventListener eventListener;

    @Autowired
    public SerialPort serialPort;

    @Value("${serialPort.baudRate}")
    private int baudRate;
    @Value("${serialPort.dataBits}")
    private int dataBits;
    @Value("${serialPort.stopBits}")
    private int stopBits;
    @Value("${serialPort.parity}")
    private int parity;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Opening port: " + serialPort.getPortName());
            serialPort.openPort();
            serialPort.setParams(baudRate,dataBits,stopBits,parity);
            serialPort.addEventListener(eventListener, 1);
        } catch (SerialPortException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Source files hierarchy:**

```
-sample (folder)
  -Model (folder)
    -ComReader.java
    -Controller.java
  -Repository (folder)
    -CRUD interfaces
  -AppStart.java
  -SpringConfig.java
```

In this case i have working program but only receive "port in used" exception.

If I remove @SpringBootApplication annotation from main class, i receive exception - **No qyalifying bean of type 'sample.Repository.CallDetailRecordRepository expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.**

If I remove @ComponentScan i receive exception - **No qualifying bean of type 'sample.Model.Controller' available;** on setContextFactory(ctx::getBean);

Comment: Doesn't `builder.run()` create an `ApplicationContext` for you? So you're starting two application contexts. What happens if you remove the line `ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);`?

Comment: @James_D, it's works fine but i declared SpringConfig now it is work properly or automaticly spring add this custom config?  // new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);

Comment: SpringBootApplication is equivalent with EnableAutoConfiguration. So yes, it adds automatically your config class.

Comment: @RinatIbragimov are you still facing the issue? If so I think I can help you... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s okay now!

I removed 
 ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfig.class);